# Version 1.0.6 "game balance adjustments" for Super Smash Bros. Wii U?

Tags: wii-u, super-smash-bros-4

The in-game update notice says just that, "Game balance adjustments."

[Nintendo support](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/13305/p/431) says the following:

> Adjustments have also been made to balance the game and make for a more pleasant gaming experience.

What has been changed? I'm noticing some AI changes I think.

Comment: I heard Diddy Kong was nerfed. Perhaps that is one of the balancing changes they've made.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The list is quite long, but you can view the balance (and other) changes here: http://www.ssbwiki.com/List_of_updates/1.0.6_changelog

Comment: I can add a list to this answer so that it isn't a link-only answer, but I think it's best to wait a few more days for the list to stabilize, since it's based on player testing and still being updated.

Comment: I wish Nintendo would have released a full changelog themselves, instead we have to rely on user testing.

Comment: Diddy Kong nerfs, good god, I'm so happy. ^_^

Answer (score 9):

Nintendo does not release any changelogs.
The only ones that exist are crowdsourced by Smashboards and r/smashbros reddit, and are done by just people noting things and testing on an unpatched system.

I do diffs of the raw data files and upload them to my website here, but I haven't done the new patch yet.
http://opensa.dantarion.com/s4/mastercore2/

The community changelog is here:
http://smashboards.com/threads/mewtwo-patch-version-1-0-6-thread-updated-sun-10pm-pst.398902/

Comment: Could you post the information from the links into your answer? The links you posed might die, which would make your answer a lot less helpful.

Comment: @Someguy112161 Normally I would agree, but the first link is a data dump that does not yet have the 1.0.6 changes (so they can't be posted here yet even if they do fit reasonably), and the second link is an ongoing forum topic that is frequently changing as users post their discoveries or suspicions. It will make more sense to post the information once the forum topic calms down and dantarion has the data to verify its claims.

Comment: And once the list settles down, a new patch will be released, anyway. <_<

Comment: @dantarion Are you the same guy who made kenbot?

Answer (score 2):

[v1.0.6 patch notes courtesy of DrWeeGee on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/smashbros/comments/32oh35/super_smash_bros_4_v106_patch_notes_compilation/)

> #### Menu/Game/Misc. Updates:
>
> - Names/Tags stay on controller ports on WiiU when switching modes
> - "Save replay" dialog box now defaults to "OK" instead of "Cancel"
> - CPU AI adjustments- Lvl. 9 AI now can drop down to the ledge and attack as you recover
> - Higher level CPUs are more likely to smash attack you when you you break shield, as opposed to a random attack
> - Wii U - after setting up amiibo to farm: the gamepad no longer shows the character screen in consecutive matches if you have turned it off
>     in the first one, it goes right to the fight.
> - Any replay from 1.0.5 (or older) will not be playable in the Replay Viewer
> - [New Sound Effects + Ryu/FE Roy](http://www.reddit.com/r/smashbros/comments/32nymz/smash_update_106_decrypted_first_observations/)
> - Pressing A+B simultaneously = smash attack (this function may be turned ON or OFF)
> - You can now turn off rumble for all controllers instead of having to do so with names
> - DLC credits added
> - The Character Select Screen has been remapped for the inclusion of Mewtwo
> - Mewtwo appears in Stage 3 of All-Star Mode only if you bought/redeemed him
> - Mewtwo's silhouette is added to the background of menus
> - Mewtwo avatar available for online profile picture
> - Mewtwo sounds added to Sound Test
> - Mewtwo has 3 trophies: the alternate, the character trophy from Classic, and the final smash from All-Star.
> - When playing FG, if you don't press any button between matches, you will be automatically disconnected
> - In the eShop tutorial there seems to be a new icon for the 3DS with no buttons, presumably because there's no standard button arrangement
>     (now thanks to the New 3DS XL)
> - Transferred Mii Fighters (from 3DS to Wii U) lose their headgear if you don't have that headgear unlocked on the Wii U version
> - Holding Up/Down with the directional stick and and trying to do a smash in that direction with the C-stick no longer does a tilt
> - Tilts/Smashes while holding an item has been removed (Link, Megaman, Peach, etc)
> - When playing with friends online, a mic soundwave next to your tag appears whenever you speak
> - RNG improved/altered for unlocking new abilities/gear/Mii head gear in all modes
> - Announcer will say "Special Smash" for special smash mode
>
> #### Character Updates:
>
> **Bowser**
>
> - Koopa Klaw (Side-B) control of movement prioritizes Bowser more
>
> **Bowser Jr.**
>
> - Fsmash improved hitbox
> - Rapid Jab (Neutral-A) has less visual whiffs
>
> **Captain Falcon**
>
> - Rapid Jab (Neutral-A) has less visual whiffs
> - Bthrow trajectory extremely small change
> - Dsmash down-angled knockback reduced (UNCONFIRMED)
>
> **Charizard**
>
> - Fire Blitz (Side-B) self damage increased 5%+4%: 9% total -> 5%+5%: 10% total
> - Uthrow buffed 8% -> 11%
> - Fair sweet/sour hitboxes switched
> - Fly (Up-B) knockback increased
>
> **Dark Pit**
>
> - No change
>
> **Diddy Kong**
>
> - Uair nerfed 8% -> 6%, knockback reduced
> - Fair nerfed 12%/10% -> 10%/8%, knockback reduced
> - Uthrow nerfed 10% -> 8%, knockback reduced
> - Dthrow nerfed 7% -> 6%, knockback unchanged but hitstun reduced
> - Monkey Flip (Side-B kick) nerfed and new hitbox 14%/12% -> 14%/12%/10%, knockback reduced
> - Monkey Flip (Side-B grab) nerfed 12% -> 10%, knockback reduced
> - Banana (throw) nerfed 7% -> 5%
> - Fsmash increased end lag
>
> **Donkey Kong**
>
> - Fsmash improved hitbox
>
> **Dr. Mario**
>
> - Fair buffed 16% -> ~<16.5%-16.8%>
> - Usmash new diagonal trajectory
>
> **Duck Hunt**
>
> - No change
>
> **Falco**
>
> - Usmash no longer whiffs the 2nd hit
>
> **Fox**
>
> - Rapid Jab (Neutral-A) has less visual whiffs
>
> **Ganondorf**
>
> - Jab (Neutral-A) buffed 8%/6%/4% -> 10%/7%/4%
> - Uthrow, Dthrow, Fthrow modified hitlag (reduced)
>
> **Greninja**
>
> - No change
>
> **Ike**
>
> - Aether Drive (Up+B) behaves normally when <1 speed in training
>
> **Jigglypuff**
>
> - Flower damage buffed 35% -> 36%
>
> **King DeDeDe**
>
> - No change
>
> **Kirby**
>
> - Dthrow buffed 6% -> 10%
> - Inhale (Neutral-B) reduced end lag
> - Flip Hammer (Side-B) less end lag
> - Final Cutter (Up-B) visual effects improved
> - Usmash and Dsmash knockback increased
>
> **Link**
>
> - Up-B buffed, uncharged 12% -> 14%, fully charged 19% -> 22%
> - Jab-infinite removed
> - Jab-cancels nerfed -> +7(?) frames
> - Usmash no longer whiffs the 2nd hit
> - Shield blocks Fox/Falco Lasers (Neutral-B)
>
> **Little Mac**
>
> - KO Punch will always take a step forward. No more wind whiffs.
> - Jolt Haymaker (Side-B) knockback increase
>
> **Lucario**
>
> - Extreme Speed RCO from low-lag landings removed
>
> **Lucina**
>
> - Shield Breaker (Neutral-B) buffed, uncharged 8% -> ~8.6%, fully charged 21% -> 23%, buffed knockback
> - Fair, Dtilt, Fsmash, Dsmash second hit buffed ~0.5%
>
> **Luigi**
>
> - Fireballs sour (like Mario's) 6%/6%/6% -> 7%/6%/5%
>
> **Mario**
>
> - No change
>
> **Marth**
>
> - No change
>
> **Mega-Man**
>
> - Ice Slasher custom fires faster and fires at the peak of your short hop instead of slightly later
> - Leaf Shield (Down-B throw) reduced start lag, increased end lag
> - RCO (Up-B) issues removed
>
> **Meta Knight**
>
> - Nair decreased end lag 20 frames -> 18 frames
> - Dimensional Cape (Down-B) landing lag bug removed
>
> **Mewtwo**
>
> - New Character
>
> **Mii Brawler**
>
> - Piston Punch "one inch punch" fixed
> - Bair nerfed 12% -> 10%
> - Fair nerfed -> -2% base damage
>
> **Mii Gunner**
>
> - No change
>
> **Mii Swordfighter**
>
> - Hero Spin (Custom Up-B 3) buffed, uncharged 12% -> 14%, fully charged 16% -> 19% on the ground
> - Dtilt buffed 6% -> 8%
> - Nair buffed 5% -> 8%
>
> **Mr. Game & Watch**
>
> - No change
>
> **Ness**
>
> - Fsmash (Bat) plays hitsound when reflecting projectiles
>
> **Olimar**
>
> - Fox-Olimar glitch removed
> - Dash-grab issue fixed
>
> **Pac-Man**
>
> - Team double Pac-Man stalling nerfed - trampolines disappear after time (UNCONFIRMED)
>
> **Palutena**
>
> - Super Speed Jump Install removed
> - Infinite Lightweight glitch on platforms has not been fixed
>
> **Peach**
>
> - Dthrow trajectory (5 degrees) changed
>
> **Pikachu**
>
> - Ledge-grab time nerfed -> +12 frames
>
> **Pit**
>
> - No change
>
> **R.O.B.**
>
> - Uthrow knockback reduced
> - Visual glitch that can cause ROBs thrusters to go off indefinitely has been fixed
>
> **Robin**
>
> - Levin Sword Durability Indicator Glitch Fixed
> - Rapid Jab (Neutral-A) has less visual whiffs
> - Tomes no longer disappear if they touch a platform
>
> **Rosalina and Luma**
>
> - Luma HP nerfed 52% -> 48%
> - Luma Dtilt 2nd hit buffed 3% -> 4%
>
> **Samus**
>
> - Ftilt has more hitboxes 6%/7% -> 5%/7%/8%
> - Regular Missiles slightly faster
>
> **Sheik**
>
> - Bair nerfed 11%/10%/5% -> 8%/7%/5%
> - Dtilt nerfed 7.5% -> 5%
>
> **Shulk**
>
> - All-Monado picture glitch with Yoshi removed
>
> **Sonic**
>
> - Bthrow nerfed
> - Spindash fully charged nerfed 10% -> 7%
> - Spindash Jump Nair nerfed ~(27%-28%) -> 22 %
> - Flame Spindash partial intangibility removed, (no longer goes through moves like Sheik needles and Fox lasers)
> - Homing Attack no longer targets objects like Duck Hunt's explosive can or Luma
>
> **Toon Link**
>
> - Dsmash hitbox properties altered - first hit knockback reduced and reduced damage, second hit whiffs if you aren't close enough
> - Shield blocks Fox/Falco Lasers (Neutral-B)
>
> **Villager**
>
> - Can't pocket Sonic's spring anymore
> - Can't pocket Pac-man's Trampoline anymore
>
> **Wario**
>
> - Little Mac KO Glitch removed
> - Bike Glitch on Palutena's Temple fixed
>
> **WiiFit Trainer**
>
> - No change
>
> **Yoshi**
>
> - Ledge Attack reduced end lag
>
> **Zelda**
>
> - Fsmash improved hitboxes
> - Bair sweetspot visuals effects improved
> - Phantom Slash slightly decreased end lag
> - Destroyed Phantom regeneration time nerfed 6 sec -> 9 sec
> - Phantom field time increased, ~1/4 sec longer after attacking
>
> **Zero Suit Samus**
>
> - No change
>
> #### Level Updates:
>
> - Omega/Lylat Cruise level edges are sloped, so you don't get stuck under the ledge anymore
> - Wuhu Island Boat instant kill glitch removed
> - Mario Circuit glitch removed(?)
> - Mewtwo's Boxing Ring title is "A Legend Reawakens".
> - Added 6 new 8-Player Stages (All Omegas):
>
>   1. Delfino Plaza
>   2. Port Town Aero Dive
>   3. Woolly World
>   4. Orbital Gate Assault
>   5. Wii Fit Studio
>   6. Pilotwings